Duplicate hyperref links after update to latest version
I am using thmtools in combination with hyperref. After updating to the latest version of TeXLive, the hyperlinks to theorems generated by \autoref no longer get unique identifiers. If I have theorem 1.1 in section 1 and theorem 2.1 in section 2. The link to the latter theorem points to the former. I know that this used to work some months ago. Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Start}

\begin{Thm}\label{thm1}
A theorem.
\end{Thm}

\section{Next}

\begin{Thm}\label{thm2}
Another theorem.
\end{Thm}

\begin{Thm}\label{thm3}
Third theorem.
\end{Thm}

Wrong link: \autoref{thm2}
Correct link: \autoref{thm3}

\end{document}


It seems to be a known bug of thmtools. A workaround was provided here: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/359
It amounts to adding the line
\renewcommand\theHThm{\thesection .\arabic {Thm}}

Alternatively, one can replace thmtools with amsthm. To gurantee the correct environment names, one needs
\newcommand{\Thmautorefname}{Theorem}

I'm wondering what is the better solution here. Is thmtools deprecated?

Please add the details of the workaround in the answer as well (in addition to the link). Currently the answer is link-only, and it will lose its value when the link stops working or the contents of the linked page changes. For Github issues this may not be very likely to happen but in principle answers (and questions) should be as self-contained as possible.

@Marijn I expanded my answer. I was hoping that someone else can give an advice what is the preferred solution.
